# Referencing all records in a subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013, subform

Is there a way to loop through all records in a subform without having to reference the specific query used to populate the subform? I'm trying to go without the whole

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strQuery As String

Set db = CurrentDb
strQuery = [some query]
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
```

declaration since it increases load time (I have 7-30 subforms on my form).

Something like

```
'Part of method within the subform, not main form
Dim rs As Recordset
rs = Form.Recordset
```

Would be nice (except the example above doesn't work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rs As Recordset
set rs = me.Recordset
```

should work: you forgot the `Set`

In older versions of Access, use:

```
set rs = me.recordsetClone
```